# jQuery: Replace attr value placeholder with user input from text input

Tags: jquery, input, placeholder, replacewith

Using `.replaceWith()` and `.val()` I was able to replace the title but when trying to access the `placeholder` `.attr()` of the input, I am unable to replace it. Here is what I have:

```
<p class="title">Title</p>
<p><input class="placeholder" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" disabled /></p>
<p><input class="newText" type="text" /></p>
<p><input class="newPlaceholder" type="text" /></p>
<p><input type="button" class="button" title="button" /></p>

$("input.button").click(function(){
    var newText = $("input.newText").val();
    $("p.title").replaceWith(newText);

    var newPlaceholder = $("input.newPlaceholder").val();
    $("input.placeholder").attr("placeholder").replaceWith(newPlaceholder);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoderLevel1/fmk39yko/23/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) isn't used to set properties of HTML elements. You want to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element

To set the placeholder property of your text box, you can use `.prop()` like this:

```
var newPlaceholder = $("input.newPlaceholder").val();
$("input.placeholder").prop("placeholder", newPlaceholder);
```

I've [updated your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmk39yko/24/) to show an example.

Comment: Thanks, I am still fairly new to jQuery and spend a lot time reading [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) but I clearly missed this.